# Using variables when referencing DOM jQuery DOM objects

Tags: jquery, variables, dom, object

I'm trying to understand why you can't construct a jQuery DOM object with a string and variable (even if the variable is also a string).

```
//Works
var test1 = $('#test');
test1.addClass('success');

//Works
var test2 = '#test';
$(test2).addClass('success');

//Fails
var test3 = 'test';
$('.' + test3).addClass('success');

//Fails
var id = 'test';
var test4 = '.' + id;
$(test4).addClass('success');
```

Here's [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QeWLu/) to demonstrate.

I feel like I'm probably missing something basic, but I can't find anything in the jQuery documentation about this.

**EDIT:** Doh, I should have noticed I used the wrong selectors in the example. I selected mcpDESIGNS' answer since it did indeed fix my jsFiddle. However, I was still getting an error in my code. ("Uncaught Exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: .") Here's what was going on in case anyone's interested:

I was trying to take the current hash in the URL, save the string as a variable, use that to construct a jQuery DOM object, and pass that object into a function.

```
var hashTag = window.location.hash;
hashTag = hashTag.substr(1);

currentObject = $('.'+hashTag);
setSpriteX(currentObject);
```

I figured out that I wasn't accounting for when there wasn't a hash in the URL. All I needed to do was add `hashTag = 'defaulthash';` before I set `currentObject`.

Comment: You're using `.` instead of `#`, `.` would be referencing a class. Am I missing something? Your DOM has no classes.

Comment: And in case it's not obvious yet, jQuery has no way to distinguish whether your selector is a bare string or a string variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have `$('#' + test3)` and `var test4 = '#' + id;` since you are trying to select by **ID**'s not classes.

`. // class selector`

`# // ID selector`

Answer (score 0):

The '.' selector is by class while the ones above are by ID. Change '.' to '#'.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing everything right as far as jQuery syntax goes. Your problem is that the `.` selector is for classes, not ID's. Use `#` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a period instead of `#`. It's an id, not a class.

```
//Fails no more
var test3 = 'test3';
$('#' + test3).addClass('success');

//Fails no more
var id = 'test4';
var test4 = '#' + id;
$(test4).addClass('success');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/QeWLu/2/

Answer (score 0):

jaypea,

1. This is a Best Method and you have to Follow, because of Cached Object is using to addClass

   //Works
   var test1 = $('#test');

   test1.addClass('success');
2. This will also works, But Performance is Down Compared to First Method Because No caching the object. Not Preferabble

   //Works
   var test2 = '#test';

   $(test2).addClass('success');

3.This will not work because you are selecting elements based on class not on ID

```
   //Fails
   var test3 = 'test';
   $('.' + test3).addClass('success');
```

Same Mistake Did in Previous, You are using Class Name Based Selector

```
//Fails
var id = 'test';
var test4 = '.' + id;
$(test4).addClass('success');
```

For More Details Check Best Practices in Jquery in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

You have only id's in your jsFiddle code, but trying toselect them by class